# BSOD: Driver State Power Failure

Tags: windows-10, bsod

For the past two weeks, I've been getting this BSOD error on my Lenovo laptop. I have even reset my laptop ("rest this PC"), but it's still happening.

My laptop details: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/quOCdcCQhxWlMLvLMd3oXhv

[My 3 dump files in zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zl8FND29UKIfmgALM_c1Rx1nljOXOjkJ/view?usp=sharing)

I have the latest Nvidia driver for my Nvidia Geforce MX150: 431.60 released on 23 Jul 2019.

I have the latest BIOS for my laptop: 8TCN53WW15  released on 15 Jul 2019.

[Lenovo Drivers and BIOS update website for my laptop model, you can check my drivers for my device here (Lenovo Ideapad 330 151kb)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/300-series/330-15ikb-type-81de/81de/81de01y1in/pf1evp57/downloads)

I have run WhoCrashed, it says it says the problem was caused by some driver which could not be identified. If I get to know the problematic driver I will update/uninstall it.

How can I analyze my dump files, so that I can find the problematic driver?

Edit 1: If you get "Oops there was a problem with the network" on google drive page while accessing dump files, just click on download. They will be downloaded. I don't know what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. The problem was the BIOS (8TCN53WW15) I had installed a month ago.

Many with the same laptop model (Ideapad 330 151kb) and BIOS posted the issue on Lenovo support forum.

As of now, there is no solution, you have to wait for a new BIOS, but there is a workaround.

1. Right-click on the desktop and go to "NVIDIA Control panel"
2. In the left panel click on "Manage 3D settings".
3. Select "High-performance NVIDIA processor" as "preferred Graphics processor".
4. Scroll down the menu until you see the option "Power management Mode" and select "preference for maximum performance".
5. Click "apply" in the bottom right corner, then exit the control panel and restart the system.

[Post on Lenovo support forum (the whole thread is in Portuguese)](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Notebooks-Lenovo-IdeaPad-e-Flex/Drive-State-Failure-Ideapad-330-15IKB/m-p/4488523#M8258)