# Windows 10: How do I reset my drivers?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

For the past 3 weeks, I have been getting this BSOD error on my laptop: Driver State Power Failure.

I have [dump files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mYEpNxcvFD9pdEEVb_5q0-44pT9ktzyN), but I have no idea how to analyse them.

I am not able to find the problematic driver, so I thought I should reset them all.

How can I reset them to factory versions?

[My previous post if you need more info.](https://superuser.com/questions/1470890/bsod-driver-state-power-failure)

Comment: Install WinDBG from the Microsoft Store to review your dump files. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: @spikey_richie I have tried it. I always get: "DebugDiag failed to locate the PEB (Process Environment Block) in 081919-50906-01.dmp, and as a result, debug analysis for this dump may be incomplete or inaccurate."

The Process Image I always get is ntkrnlmp.exe. I've read that it's not the problematic driver, but it gets blamed most of the time during BSOD errors.

Comment: From a quick look, I can see that the NVIDIA driver is mentioned in all crash dumps. That doesn’t mean it’s (entirely) to blame, but updating it can’t hurt.

Comment: @DanielB I had the latest driver: 430.60 (for MX150), I rolled back (419.71) thinking it would solve the problem.

Comment: Did you do a full clean install of the nVidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled it (430.60) from the device manager and installed 419.71.

Comment: After analyzing the dump, the problem seems that the NVIDIA GeForce MX150 driver "failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time". The latest driver is [version 436.02 for Windows 10 64-bit](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/150302). Why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

You uninstall the device and check delete the driver. Start with the display adapter(s). You can try the three drivers you can see on your Lenovo page. Also try to get Intel to install the newest driver.

Comment: I downloaded the latest intel driver. The install failed, It said intel doesn't have the permission to install it and I should wait till Lenovo releases it. Lenovo releases drivers 2-3 months late.

Do you think I should install the Intel VGA driver manually (previously I had downloaded the .exe setup file)

I had the latest Nvidia driver as well, I rolled back thinking it would solve it, but no.

I downloaded WinDBG to analyze dump files to find the faulty driver, but it always says "failed to locate the PEB in .dmp" and blames it on ntkrnlmp.exe which I am sure is not the culprit.

Comment: I would simply uninstall the Intel drivers if you have a Nvidia GPU installed.  If you suspect the problem is due to the Intel driver, best remove it entirely, to eliminate it from the equation.